# Android: Table Row Image is fattened and does not maintain aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, mobile, imageview, aspect-ratio

I have an ImageView inside a TableRow which needs to basically display the image by maintaining its aspect ratio. However this is what I end up with:

[image]

Here's my XML for the TableLayout and that specific row only:

```
<TableLayout
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="5dip" >

                 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/producImagScroller"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/girl2" >
                 </ImageView>
      </TableRow>
```

What do you think is wrong?

**EDIT:**
After trying Greg Ennis's answer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
android:background="@drawable/girl2"
```

You should set

```
android:src="@drawable/girl2"
```

After doing this, try adjusting the image `scaleType` attribute. (Works only if you change `background` to `src`).

Comment: Actually that image is dynamically changed by: imgScroll.setImageDrawable(drawableArray[1]); is that the reason for the misbehavior?

Comment: Well thats a nice detail to drop in. The setImageDrawable does not replace the background image - Why are you setting a background image in the xml? why 2 images?

Comment: Hmm okay I removed the background. Still no luck sir.

Comment: Initially I needed to set a backup image in case there was no other image to be dynamically set, that's why

Comment: Did you try calling `setScaleType` like I indicated in my answer?

Comment: I did this: imgScroll.setImageDrawable(drawableArray[1]); imgScroll.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Comment: FIT_XY is your problem. Change it to FIT_CENTER

Comment: Okay that made the picture small Greg. Edited the question and added a screenshot of it

Comment: Of course. It has to scale the image to fit. What else can it do? If you set it to CENTER_CROP, it fills the entire view, but only a small section of the image. So make the imageview and row height larger (or use wrap_content height)

Comment: So what I should do is to manually set about 300dp for the ImageView and the row? Is that okay?